# How to ollect all the outside tag numbers

Tags: jquery

I want to collect the numbers extracoronal -- what is the correct way to do this?

```
<body>
<div id="HQ"></div>    

<table class="table" border="2">
<tr>
<td>AAAA</td>
<td>
<span class="A"></span>
"6"
<span class="B"></span>
"4"
<span class="C"></span>
"5"
<span class="D"></span>
"5"
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="table" border="2">
<tr>
<td>AAAA</td>
<td>
<span class="A"></span>
"9"
<span class="B"></span>
"4"
<span class="C"></span>
"2"
<span class="D"></span>
"2"
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="table" border="2">
<tr>
<td>AAAA</td>
<td>
<span class="A"></span>
"7"
<span class="B"></span>
"4"
<span class="C"></span>
"5"
<span class="D"></span>
"1"
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

scirpt :

```
<script>

$(function(){

var texts = $('td *').map(function() {
    if (this.nextSibling.nodeType == 3)
        return this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
});

var a = texts[0];
var b = texts[1];
var c = texts[2];
var d = texts[3];

A = Number(a)
B = Number(b)
C = Number(c)
D = Number(d)

$("#HQ").html(A);
});
</script>
```

I want to collect all the numbers inside the table.

I just want `class="A"`.

```
<span class="A"></span>
 "6"

6 + 7 + 9 = 22
```

Tried the code above, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text for all elements with the class of "A", use this:

```
$('.A').text
```

Comment: `text`(method) returns the text content of the selected elements but in OP's code, numbers are sibling textNodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `each` method.

```
$(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('td').find('span').each(function() {
       var n = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/"/g, '');
       total += parseInt(n, 10);
    });
    $('#HQ').text(total)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vDvnx/

Answer (score 0):

This version retrives only the numbers after the `A` class and outputs the equation

```
$(function() {
    var nums=[];
    var tot=0;

    $('td:has(.A)').each(function(){
        var $contents=$(this).contents();
        var numTxt=$contents.filter('.A')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/"/g,'')
        var num=parseInt(numTxt,10)
       nums.push(numTxt);
        tot+=num
    });
   $('body').append('<br><br>'+ nums.join('+') +'='+tot) ;  

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqat4/